# Produce Hierarchical Random Graph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am trying to fit a Hierarchical Random Graph model to an edgelist (represents interactions in an unweighted, undirected large network), and measure clustering and path length of the model. I am not quite sure if what I am doing is correct as I may not be grasping the documentation fully.

Here is the code.

```
#Import Edgelist, convert to igraph
imported_g=read.csv('graph_edgelist.csv',header=FALSE,check.names=FALSE)
g=graph.data.frame(imported, directed=FALSE, vertices=NULL)

#Calculate parameters, make sure network is ok.
transitivity(g)
>0.3352213
average.path.length(g)
>3.6299


#Fit HRG model, convert back to igraph object to measure metrics.  
hrg_model = hrg.fit (g, hrg = g, start = FALSE, steps = 0)
igraph_hrg=as.igraph(hrg_model)

#Measure metrics of fit_hrg
average.path.length(igraph_hrg)
>50
transitivity(igraph_hrg)
>0
```

Basically, the metrics of the igraph model are very different from the edgelist I imported (it has a much lower path length and higher clustering). I thought this meant that the model failed to capture the attributes of the edgelist, but then I am not sure I am generating a HRG model.

What is the difference between fitting the HRG model to a graph, and actually generating a HRG from which I can measure useful parameters? Would it be the igraph function hrg.create?

The igraph code is based on here:
http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/hierarchy/

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the `hrg=...` argument to `hrg.fit` - it should be used only if you have a HRG model that you want to use as a starting point. (And it is ignored anyway unless you set `start` to `TRUE`). Otherwise your code seems correct - and note that the HRG model never intended to capture the average path length or the transitivity of the original graph. I have done a few experiments a while ago with several random graph models to see how closely they reproduce different structural properties of some biological networks, and my results showed that hierarchical random graph models tend to do pretty well in reproducing the mean degree and mean vertex-vertex distance of a network but fall short in reproducing average vertex transitivities or motif occurrences - but to be fair, I haven't really found any other random graph models that do this job well either.

> What is the difference between fitting the HRG model to a graph, and actually generating a HRG from which I can measure useful parameters?

*Fitting* the model takes an actual (real) graph and finds parameters for the hierarchical random graph model that approximate the real graph well (in some sense). The *generation* step takes a parameterized HRG model (typically established from a previous fitting step) and then creates *another* graph. This is implemented in `sample_hrg`.

> Would it be the igraph function hrg.create?

No, `hrg.create` takes a binary tree representation of the structure of an HRG model (similar to the plots you see in Aaron's paper) and then creates an HRG model object that you can pass to `sample_hrg` later on.

Comment: Thank you so much. So my understanding is that 1) fit_hrg just takes my edgelist and provides parameters for an HRG. 2) hrg.create takes these parameters and creates an object which I can then use to create the final HRG with sample_hrg? Would this be the complete pipeline?

Comment: However, the original authors of the HRG paper DO compare the clustering coefficients and path lengths of the HRG graphs to the original graphs they are derived from.

Comment: No, the complete pipeline is simply `fit_hrg` followed by `sample_hrg` - `fit_hrg` already returns a HRG object. `hrg.create` is useful only if you want to construct a HRG object "manually" from a HRG "drawing" that you have in the paper.